# What's the trick for proving one eigenvalue of orthogonal matrix is $-1$ if the determinant is $-1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, orthonormal

Obviously, the magnitude of the orthogonal matrix is 1, which is easy to prove.. However, I wonder how can one prove that the eigenvalue of an orthogonal matrix is $-1$, if the determinant of this matrix is $-1$?

Thanks a lot.

Thanks for the help that I can prove it now from the conjugate pairs point of view.

Is there a method by proving that $\det(I+A)=0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: nonreal eigenvalues of real orthogonal matrices must occur in conjugate pairs, and the product of a conjugate pair of complex number is ...

Comment: And the product of a conjugate pair of complex number is the magnitude, which is positive number, therefore, there has to be at least one negative eigenvalue, and therefore has to be -1. Thnaks a lot !

Comment: If determinant is -1? I still don't get it

Comment: @user21795 There is a theorem which says the product of the eigenvalues equals the determinant.